# Hidden tests keep failing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written this piece of code that returns an array of odd numbers or even numbers depending on which of the arguments are greater than each other.

```
    const number_game = (x, y) => {
    //   Code here
    let numbersArray = [];
    if (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') {
        if (x > y) {
            for (let i = y + 1; i < x; i++) {
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    numbersArray.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if (y > x) {
            for (let i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
                if (i % 2 === 1) {
                    numbersArray.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if (y === x) {
            return numbersArray;
        }


        return numbersArray;
    }
    else {
        return `${x} and ${y} should be numbers`
    }
}
console.log(number_game(3,13));
```

I have tested it with possible cases and it works but it keeps failing a hidden test online saying **"expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ] or expected [ Array(10) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]"**. I have tried to tweak my solution in different ways but it still didn't work. I want to know what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it.

**P.S**: A search on deepEquality reveals that "The assert.deepEqual() method tests if two objects, and their child objects, are equal, using the == operator". 
I just can't seem to point where the error is specifically.

Comment: Or the task text please?

Comment: Edit this and put it in your question

Comment: `let i = x + 1` and `let i = y + 1`; Your current code does not produce results _**between**_ the two integers.

Comment: @RandyCasburn infact that was how my first solution looked like but it returned **"expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]"** on submission.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. It's possible the tests are invalid.

Comment: Well...I hope so

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could do was simplify it a bit.

```js
const number_game = (x, y) => {
  var isOdd = x > y;
  let numbersArray = [];
  if (typeof x != "number" || typeof y != "number") {
    return "${x} and ${y} should be numbers";
  }
  for (let i = (isOdd ? y : x) + 1; i < (isOdd ? x : y); i++) {
    if (i % 2 === (isOdd ? 0 : 1)) {
      numbersArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  return numbersArray;
};

console.log(number_game(13, 3));
```

Comment: I like your approach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So after much inquisitiveness and research, I discovered that the problem specs and the test cases are in conflict. An input of (12, 0) should yield => [2,4,6,8,10] according to the problem specs but that result will return this error as a failed test **"expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ] or expected [ Array(10) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]"**. However, I observed that when I remove the + 1 from let i = x + 1 and y = x + 1 and I add the equal to sign to i <=x and i <=y termination conditions, the test passes. The adjustment, however, returns this result [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ] which is not correct with the problem specs. This is the code that passed the test:

```
const number_game = (x, y) => {
    //   Code here
    let numbersArray = [];
    if (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') {
        if (x > y) {
            for (let i = y; i <= x; i++) {
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    numbersArray.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (let i = x; i <= y; i++) {
                if (i % 2 === 1) {
                    numbersArray.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return numbersArray;
    }
    else {
        return `${x} and ${y} should be numbers`
    }
}
```